# Dev C++ Console Window Won't Close

Tags: c++, console, dev-c++

I recently installed Dev C++ and tested it with a simple console output program, and after doing so I tried to close the console... to no avail. Clicking out, alt-f4ing, ending process, and just about every other way I could think of to close the console (including restarting the computer, which just reopened the console windows again upon startup) just made ConsolePauser.exe work for a couple seconds and then remain open.
Anyway, there may be a simple fix for this, but as of right now I can't find one and it's pretty irritating.
Thanks.

Comment: so this is Dev C++'s "work" console window or one for your own program?

Comment: Just the default debugging console window.

Comment: it stays out after the program has exited?